# Error Elastic Search YML Homestead Configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, homestead

I want to install configuration with my homestead.
But currently I have a problem to my elasticsearch configuration.
If I add network.host: 192.168.10.10 in my elasticsearch.yml, i can't run my elasticsearch.

If someone has problem like me?

This is my snippet elasticsearch.yml

```
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
network.host: 192.168.10.10
```

Comment: Can you post the full error log?

Answer (score 1):

**1. add ports to the homestead.yaml**

`ports:
    - send: 9200
      to: 9200`

**2. install java**

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer -y`

**3. install elasticsearch**

`wget -qO - https://packages.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://packages.elastic.co/elasticsearch/2.x/debian stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elasticsearch-2.x.list`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install elasticsearch -y`

`sudo update-rc.d elasticsearch defaults 95 10`

**4. then open any editor, for example nano**

`sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`

add **network.host: 192.168.10.10** by type

[my elasticsearch.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZEnE.png)

**5. start the service**

`sudo service elasticsearch start`

and check: `curl http://192.168.10.10:9200`